# Setting selected elements in a UI tree widget

Tags: java

I have a Swing vector-program similar to [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) targeting RAD. There are some plug-ins that let you

- create structures like **Rectangle**, **Text** and **Circle** but also complex types like **Table-Columns**.
- generate files like **Spring-Roo-Script**, **grails-script**, **SQL-Files** and svg-Files.

In the Center you have the Drawing-Panel (`DrawPanel`), on the right side you have the component-tree.

In the `DrawPanel` class, this is the function `select` that I need a review for. This function changes the selected nodes in the Tree on the right.

```
/** The main tab where paint areas are. Never <code>null</code>. */
@Inject
Tab tab;

public void select(Set<? extends TreeNode> newSelection,
        boolean layersModified) {
    boolean inAssertMode = false;
    assert inAssertMode = true;
    if (inAssertMode && getSelection().equals(newSelection)) {
        if (!layersModified) {
            throw new UnnecessaryOperationException("Select tree Nodes",
                    getSelection(), newSelection);
        }
        LOG.severe("I did not noticed about changed selection, "
                + "you only notify about modified layers!");
    }
    Set<TreePath> c = new HashSet<>();
    for (TreeNode newSelected : newSelection) {
        c.add(new TreePath(newSelected));
    }
    TreePath[] array = c.toArray(new TreePath[0]);
    setSelectionPaths(array);
    if (layersModified) {
        tab.getCurrentDrawPanel().notifyLayersModified();
    }
}
```

As you will notice, the code above is only executed if asserations are enabled.